# What does "object required error" mean?

Tags: excel, vba

My code below is hitting an "object required error". Can you help me understand what is wrong?

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()
   Dim sPath As String
   Dim sFil As String
   Dim strName As String
   Dim twbk As Workbook
   Dim owbk As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   Set twbk = ActiveWorkbook
   sPath = "C:\Adise\Export\" 'Change to suit
   sFil = Dir(sPath & "*.xls")

   Do While sFil <> ""
      strName = sPath & sFil
      Set owbk = Workbooks.Open(strName)
      Set ws = owbk.Sheets(1)
      ws.Range("A1", Range("A" & Row.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
      twbk.Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      owbk.Close False 'Close no save
      sFil = Dir
   Loop

   twbk.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Although this isn't the clearest question, it does contain code and it does list the error in the title - and it did get two answers, which would seem to contradict the "not a real question" classification. Rather than close I would have asked for the line with the error, although it's pretty clear which one it is. So I vote to re-open.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

Problem with this line: `ws.Range("A1", Range("A" & Row.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy`

You can use to find last row `Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row`

alternatively you can use `Range("A1").CurrentRegion` to include the entire current region.

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFil As String
    Dim strName As String
    Dim twbk As Workbook
    Dim owbk As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set twbk = ActiveWorkbook
    sPath = "C:\Adise\Export\"    'Change to suit
    sFil = Dir(sPath & "*.xls")

    Do While sFil <> ""
        strName = sPath & sFil
        Set owbk = Workbooks.Open(strName)
        Set ws = owbk.Sheets(1)
        ws.Range("A1", Range("A" & Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row)).Copy twbk.Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
        owbk.Close False    'Close no save
        sFil = Dir
    Loop

    twbk.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be plural - `Rows`, not Row. :

```
ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
```

`Rows.Count` returns the number of rows in the worksheet: 65536 for Excel 2003 and earlier and 1,048,576 for Excel 2007 onwards. For this reason you should also change the next line to:

```
twbk.Sheets(1).Range("A" & twbk.Sheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

You should also qualify the `Ranges` with `ws`, as above.